# current_date is give search result with a timestamp column in postgres

Tags: java, sql, postgresql

I have a column of type varchar which stores date with timestamp, and without timestamp in postgres.
While trying to hit the below query,

```
select * from table where cast(column as date) = CURRENT_DATE::date
```

it is returning those columns also which has date with timestamp also. How can I modify the query to find the exact match of only dates and not with timestamp.

sample input data:

```
Column1
2022-12-09 17:38:53.415367
2022-12-09
```

Expected output:

```
2022-12-09
```

Actual: getting both the columns in the result

```
2022-12-09 17:38:53.415367
2022-12-09
```

Comment: `CURRENT_DATE::date` can be simplified to `CURRENT_DATE`

Comment: Well the columns that store date & time (I assume you mean that with "date with timestamp") will be longer, so maybe `where length("column") = 10 and cast(...) = current_date`

Comment: 1) Mixing two types `date` and `timestamp` in a column of a third type `varchar` is not a good idea. 2) Why does the presence of a time matter? `cast(column as date)` is going to make it a `date`.

Comment: If you want to filter out the `timestamps` and keep the `dates` then: `select * from table where column::timestamp  = CURRENT_DATE + time '00:00:00';`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name simplifying to current_date also does no help .. It still retrieves me all the columns. 
Also checking the length of a column will work, but I was looking for a more generic fix may be from the function itself

Comment: @AdrianKlaver  Ideally cast(column as date) this is making it to date, but its returing all those dates as well which are having timestamps as well .. That is something I want to filter out. I just want exact match with the dates

Comment: I never said that removing the redundant cast would change anything. And yes `select *` will retrieve all columns. If you don't want that then don't use `select *`. Without more details this is impossible to answer. Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I have added more details to the query, please let me know your input over it

Comment: Well, the query I suggested: `where length(the_column) = 10 and cast(the_column as date) = current_date` works with that example. https://dbfiddle.uk/w2P539AE

Answer (score 0):

Per my comment:

```
SELECT
    t.dt_val
FROM (
    VALUES ('2022-12-09'),
        ('2022-12-09 17:38:53.415367')) AS t (dt_val)
WHERE
    t.dt_val::timestamp = '2022-12-09'::date + '00:00:00'::time;

 dt_val   
------------
 2022-12-09
```

I used `'2022-12-09'::date` instead of `current_date` to make the answer relevant in the future. At time of answer `current_date` resolves to `'2022-12-09'::date`.